# How to schedule MySQL event during weekend days

Tags: mysql

I would like to trigger an update during the weekend but I failed with many attempts.
I am looking for something like this:

```
CREATE EVENT on_weekend
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
STARTS 'e.g., every Saturday 00:00' ENDS 'e.g., every Monday 00:00'
DO Update...;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this,

```
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK STARTS '2014-11-23 12:20:01' ENDS '2015-01-31 12:20:01'
```

please see [http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Event/Eventscheduleeveryweek.htm]